# How to read JSON/excel file located in the same directory of index.html by HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, json, excel

I want to implement a web page which only display information from the file in the same directory of index.html. But I dont know how to read a JSON/excel file by HTML/JS and I know I can read .txt file by using iframe and specifying source. But the txt file is not suitable for categorying the content and display in a table.
Could anyone give me a hand on this? Thanks~

Comment: Is there any chance to make that file as .csv file?

Comment: Your question is about xls/xlsx or json file. they are very very different.

Comment: Any formatted and easy to edit file type is acceptable. The primary purpose is to let ppl with little technical knowledge update these file and make the content display on webpage.